# how to find the particular db and table is already there or not in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile-application

I'm a new android developer and developing an application that has a login screen.

When the application starts it checks if the database (LoginDB) exists or not. If it does not exist then I want to create the database, create the table and insert 1 row. If the database exists then it will continue the application execution.

How do you find out if a particular database exists and if the needed table is already there or not.

Im using **android 2.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the table is exists or not in the perticular db.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("your db file name",
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
Cursor cursor = db.query("sqlite_master", new String[] { "name" },
                "name=" + "'your table name'", null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
   //Table is not exists
}
else 
{
   //table is exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **SQLiteOpenHelper** class has two methods onCreate and onUpdate which exactly does what you need. If there is no database, then it will call the onCreate method and if it is present it will call the onUpdate method. Check [Vogellas site](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for a nice example

Answer (score 0):

Using this query you can check whether table is exist in DB or not,

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```

otherwise,

in onCreate of database helper you have to use create query like as follow,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename+" ( "+ colums+");");
```